Is it correct to claim that Hawking-Page phase transition is related to the breaking point at the Page-time?
In the evaporation process of a Black Hole in an AdS space we have a Hawking-Page phase transition. We know that such a phase transition can be exhibited by a singular behavior. At the other hand, there exists one breaking point in the corresponding Page curve, denoted as Page-time. Is it correct to claim that Hawking-Page phase transition is related to the breaking point at the Page-time?
